# Struct sscanf not working as it should?

Tags: c, file, struct, fgets, scanf

i am trying to sipmply input some data into a struct from a file.
I have used the same excact code in a different program and it works as it should?
I dont know where i am wrong.
Shouldnt the code below work ? Maybe i am not that familiar with sscanf .I would like some help. Thank you.

```
The txt file is like this:
foo.var 1241
poa.org 421
aeraf.gr 5456
oiggdf.po 98843
```

Code:

```
struct filedata
{
    char fname[50];
    int fsize;
};

int main()
{
    char line[60];
    int i=0;
    int numberoffiles=0;
    int lines=0;
    int ch=0;

    FILE *fp = fopen("mytext.txt","r");
    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
            if (ch == '\n')
                lines++;
    }

    struct filedata file[lines];
    numberoffiles=lines + 1;

    if(fp == (FILE*)NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Cannot Open File\n");
        exit (-1);
    }
    else
    {
        while (fgets(line,60,fp)!=NULL)
        {
            sscanf(line,"%s %d",file[i].fname,&file[i].fsize);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem, besides "it don't work"?

Comment: Well, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: i am only using a space between the name and the size.
Thank you though Jonathan.Its working fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop that counts the number of lines reads the entire file so that the current position is at the end of the file when you begin your second loop. Consider using `rewind()` before your second loop to move back to the start of the file.

Also, your test to see if `fp` is NULL should go right after the `open()` call. Otherwise, your code that reads the number of lines will fail.

Comment: aww is there a way to get past this?